# How can I implement a command line option in Bazel to switch between which dependency version is used for building?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, bazel, bazel-rules

For some background, the C++ program I am working on has the possibility to interoperate with some other applications that use various Protobuf versions. In the source code for my program, I have the compiled .pb.cc files from these other applications for the Protobuf interface. These .pb.cc files were compiled with a particular version of Protobuf, and I don't have any control over this. I am using Bazel to build, and I want to be able to specify a Bazel build configuration for my program, which will use a particular version of Protobuf which matches that of one of the possible other applications.

Originally, I wanted to put something in the .bazelrc file so that I can specify a particular version of Protobuf depending on the config, for example:

```
# in .bazelrc:
build:my_config --protobuf_version=3_20_1
build:my_other_config --protobuf_version=3_21_6
```

Then from the terminal, I could build with the command

```
bazel build --config=my_config //path/to/target:target
```

which would build as if I had typed

```
bazel build --protobuf_version=3_20_1 //path/to/target:target
```

At this point, I wanted to use the `select()` function, as detailed in the Bazel docs for [Configurable Build Attributes](https://bazel.build/docs/configurable-attributes), to use a particular Protobuf version during building. But, the Protobuf dependencies are all specified in the WORKSPACE file, which is more limited than a BUILD file, and this `select()` function cannot be used there. So then my idea was to pull in every version of the Protobuf library that I would possibly need, and give them different names in the WORKSPACE file, and then in the BUILD files, use a `select()` function to  choose the correct version. But, the Bazel rule for compiling the `proto_library` is used as such:

```py
proto_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["foo.proto"],
    strip_import_prefix = "/foo/bar/baz",
)
```

I don't see of any opportunity to use a `select()` function here to specify which Protobuf version's `proto_library` rule should be used. The `proto_library` rule is also defined in from the WORKSPACE file with:

```py
load("@rules_proto//proto:repositories.bzl", "rules_proto_dependencies", "rules_proto_toolchains")
rules_proto_dependencies()
rules_proto_toolchains()
```

Now, I would say that I am stuck. I don't see a way to specify on the command line which version of Protobuf should be used with the `proto_library` rule.

In the end, I would like a way to do the equivalent in the WORKSPACE file of

```py
# in WORKSPACE
if my_config:
    # specific protobuf version:
    http_archive(
      name = "com_google_protobuf",
      sha256 = "8b28fdd45bab62d15db232ec404248901842e5340299a57765e48abe8a80d930",
      strip_prefix = "protobuf-3.20.1",
      urls = ["https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/archive/v3.20.1.tar.gz"],
    )
elif my_other_config:
    # same as above, but with different version
else:
    # same as above, but with default version
```

According to some [google groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/5YcfHqVCWds), this doesn't seem to be possible in the WORKSPACE file, so I would need to do it in a BUILD file, but the dependencies are specified in the WORKSPACE.

Comment: There is way to do it using Bzlmod as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73567300/multiple-versions-of-external-repo-in-workspace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a way that works that seems to go against Bazel's philosophy, but most importantly does what I want.

The repository dependencies are loaded in the first of two steps, the first involving the `WORKSPACE` file, and the second involving the `BUILD` file. Command line flags for the build cannot be normally be directly passed to the `WORKSPACE`, but it is possible to get some information to the `WORKSPACE` by setting an environment variable and creating a [`repository_rule`](https://bazel.build/extending/repo). In the `WORKSPACE`, this  environment variable can be used, for example, to change the url argument to `http_archive` which specifies the dependency version.

This repository rule is created in a separate file .bzl file, which is then loaded in the `WORKSPACE`.  As a generalized example of how get environment variable values into the `WORKSPACE`, the following file `my_repository_rule.bzl` could be created:

```py
# in file my_repository_rule.bzl
def _my_repository_rule_impl(repository_ctx):
    # read the particular environment variable we are interested in
    config = repository_ctx.os.environ.get("MY_CONFIG_ENV_VAR", "")

    # necessary to create empty BUILD file for this rule
    # which will be located somewhere in the Bazel build files
    repository_ctx.file("BUILD")

    # some logic to do something based on the value of the environment variable passed in:
    if config.lower() == "example_config_1":
        ADDITIONAL_INFO = "foo"
    elif config.lower() == "example_config_2":
        ADDITIONAL_INFO = "bar"
    else:
        ADDITIONAL_INFO = "baz"

    # create a temporary file called config.bzl to be loaded into WORKSPACE
    # passing in any desired information from this rule implementation
    repository_ctx.file("config.bzl", content = """
MY_CONFIG = {}
ADDITIONAL_INFO = {}
""".format(repr(config), repr(ADDITIONAL_INFO ))
    )


my_repository_rule = repository_rule(
    implementation=_my_repository_rule_impl,
    environ = ["MY_CONFIG_ENV_VAR"]
)
```

This can be used in the `WORKSPACE` as such:

```py
# in file WORKSPACE
load("//:my_repository_rule.bzl", "my_repository_rule ")
my_repository_rule(name = "local_my_repository_rule ")
load("@local_my_repository_rule //:config.bzl", "MY_CONFIG", "ADDITIONAL_INFO")

print("MY_CONFIG = {}".format(MY_CONFIG))
print("ADDITIONAL_INFO = {}".format(ADDITIONAL_INFO))
```

When a target is built with `bazel build`, the `WORKSPACE` will receive the value of the `MY_CONFIG_ENV_VAR` from the terminal and store it in the Starlark variable `MY_CONFIG`, and any other additional information determined in the implementation.

The environment variable can be passed by normal means, such as typing in a bash shell, for example:

```bash
MY_CONFIG_ENV_VAR=example_config_1 bazel build //path/to/target:target
```

It can also be passed as a flag with the [`--repo_env`](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--repo_env) flag. This flag sends an extra environment variable to be available to the repository rules, meaning the following is equivalent:

```bash
bazel build --repo_env=MY_CONFIG_ENV_VAR=example_config_1 //path/to/target:target
```

This can be made easier to switch between by including the following in the `.bazelrc` file:

```
# in file .bazelrc
build:my_config_1 --repo_env=MY_CONFIG_ENV_VAR=example_config_1
build:my_config_2 --repo_env=MY_CONFIG_ENV_VAR=example_config_2
```

So running `bazel build --config=my_config_1 //path/to/target:target` will show the debug output from the `print` statements in `WORKSPACE` as the following:

```
MY_CONFIG = example_config_1
ADDITIONAL_INFO = foo
```

If `ADDITIONAL_INFO` in the rule implementation (in the file `my_repository_rule.bzl`) were set to a version number such as `"3.20.1"`, then the WORKSPACE could, for example, use this in an `http_archive` call to pull the desired version of the dependency.

```py
# in file WORKSPACE
if ADDITIONAL_INFO == "3.20.1":
    sha256 = "8b28fdd45bab62d15db232ec404248901842e5340299a57765e48abe8a80d930"

http_archive(
  name = "com_google_protobuf",
  sha256 = sha256,
  strip_prefix = "protobuf-{}".format(ADDITIONAL_INFO),
  urls = ["https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/archive/v{}.tar.gz".format(ADDITIONAL_INFO)],
)
```

Of course, the value of the `sha256` kwarg could also be passed in from the repository rule as a separate string variable, or as part of a dictionary, for example.